# How to use $ for jQuery inside domready when prototype is using $ outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

I'm unable to remove prototype from a JSF framework (RichFaces 3.3.3). And if I try noConflict and try to take over $ it breaks my application framework because its tightly coupled with prototype.

So is there a way that I can do this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    /*
        some code that within this domready function 
        allows me to use $() within this function
        and not interfere with $ being used for prototype
        outside?
    */
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's already passed in as the first parameter to your `ready` handler, just use:

```
jQuery(function($) { 
  $("selector").doSomething();
});
//$ is still prototype here
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can write `var $ = jQuery;` to replace the `$` symbol within a single function.

In your specific case, you can also use the first parameter of the callback.

Answer (score 0):

taking this [link](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) as a reference, you could do something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) { // like Nick Craver
});
```

and call the functions you need to have jQuery with:

```
var yourFunction = function(){
   var $ = this;
};

yourFunction.call(jQuery);

...

var yourFunction = (function($){

   return function() {

       // $ -> jQuery

   };

})(jQuery);

...

var yourFunction = (function(){

   var $ = this;

   return function() {

       // $ -> jQuery

   };

}).call(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard within my working group:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
    //Do jQuery stuff using $ here.
})(jQuery);
//Do prototype stuff using $ here
```